# urdf error. It have some including xacro files

Tags: ros2, urdf, parameters, xml

I used the `include` xacro command to combine three urdf.xacro files into one, and only one xacro is loaded through XML conversion from 'robot_description' via `"$(xacro path/to/file.urdf.xacro)"`.
This worked normally in Launch (on `launch.py`), but failed when I put it directly in params or handled it in param files. But I want to operate it in run command.

Command:

```
-p robot_description:="$(xacro ws_moveit/urdf/example_robot.urdf.xacro)"
```

Results in:

```
[rcl]: Failed to parse global arguments
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLInvalidROSArgsError'
  what():  failed to initialize rcl: Couldn't parse parameter override rule: '-p robot_description:=<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem is address.